# Overload for 'confirmbtn_Click' matches delegate 'RoutedEventHandler'

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<Button x:Name="confirmbtn" Content="Register"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="60"
        Margin="0,286,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="216" 
        Click="confirmbtn_Click"/>t
```

```
private void confirmbtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e, MainWindow mainWindowInstance)
{
 ///
}
```

I'm trying to get the MainWindow mainWindowInstance here, but everytime I place it somewhere I get the same error over and over again

Comment: You just can't add your own parameters to the click event.  Remove the `MainWindow mainWindowInstance` part.

Comment: Read about [event handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/#event-handlers), you can't change their signatures. To get instance of `mainWindow` inside handler you need to use other ways, e.g. using instance members to pass value. You are likely have it already as `this` (if this handler is located inside `MainWindow`).

Comment: [Introduction to delegates and events in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/delegates-overview)

Answer (score 0):

Every event has uniqe signature and you cannot change it. To get instance of mainWindow you can use other ways. For example, you can use this code:

```
Window mainWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow;
```

or you can get the window that is parent of this button with this code (note: this might not be the main window if the argument is the child of a different window instance!)

```
private Window FindParentWindow(DependencyObject element)
{
    if (element is Window parentWindow)
    {
      return parentWindow;
    }

    DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element);

    // Check if this is the root of the visual tree
    return parent is null
      ? null
      : FindParentWindow(parent);
}

private void confirmbtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  // This might not be the main window 
  // if the argument is the child of a different window instance!
  Window mainWindow = FindParentWindow(sender as DependencyObject);
}
```

or you are likely having it already as this (if this handler is located inside MainWindow).

Comment: `Application.Current.MainWindow` is the only solution to get the reference of the main window. This is because it guarantees to return the main window and it doesn't have to traverse any element trees (performance). Your `FindParentWindow` does not (necessarily) return the main window. It returns the root window of the current visual tree. This could be any window instance or NULL if the element is a child of a disconnected visual tree (when there is no Window in the hierarchy). For example, if the Button is located inside a dialog, then the method would return this dialog (if it is a Window).